# When navigating back to form page, Angular2 should add "has-error" css class (bootstrap) to my form fields, but it does not add the class

Tags: angular

When navigating back to form page, Angular2 should add "has-error" css class (bootstrap) to my form fields, but it does not add the class.

I created a multi step form wizard where the user can freely navigate back and forth through all wizard step without being blocked by validation rules on the individual pages. However I would want my validation error (informational) to be visible on the formpage. Example: border input field in red color(css class). As long as there are validation errors the user is not allowed to commit (save/submit) button in the last step. (I made provisions on my screen to keep the user informed of all error locations displayed in another window which visually gives an overall picture of all the formwizard steps.)

**Context:** I use a state service to keep all user input data centralized. This approach also allows for loading (restoring) data/formstate during navigation. I was confronted with some challenges around validation and Control's states (touched/dirty/valid). I still have them btw. I hope the Angular team will provide state reset of Controls.

**Problem:** When navigating back to a previous form:

1) The form to be displayed at the arriving page will be populated with the data previously entered by the user (data restore)

2) validation will be triggered manually

3) fields should be properly rendered depending of the state (touched/dirty/valid)

Challenge lies at point 3). At the moment I can not manage to highlight(red) a field with known validation error. I suppose because I am setting the data manually in the inputfields (no user interaction) and therefor I am not triggering the fieldvalidation. I discovered that my expected/desired behaviour would work only after an onblur event when the user would interact with the field.

**Question:** Does anyone have a working solution based on my intent described above? I want that my fields with validationerrors be highlighted (css class i.e. has-error) as soon as I navigate back to my form containing data which have been entered previously.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want user to not move untill he valids the form OR navigate success fully back with removing all validations

Comment: This approach let a user navigate back and forth through all pages even though there are validation errors per page. Ultimately the user has to resolve all errors before committing (that is submitting to the backend) the form. Example: errors are visually marked on the screen to inform the user which fields are not valid but he may for the time being choose to navigate forth to other pages and come back eventually to correct the error.

Comment: give an example but simple not so much theory its confusing